# How to lock and encrypt folder and files

Tags: 12.10, encryption, ecryptfs

I installed cryptkeeper in my laptop and when I click on the icon, it is not opening up or responding.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit version. Please help me on how to use this software or tell me how to lock/encrypt my files and folders.

Answer (score 2):

I've used encfs from the command line and it works well in Ubuntu 12.10. The program you're trying to use, cryptkeeper, is a Gnome tray applet which brings encfs to a graphical window. However cryptkeeper seems to work with earlier versions of Ubuntu. I also use Ubuntu 12.10 and couldn't get the applet to appear despite cryptkeeper showing as a process in 'top'. I would guess that it's not compatible with the Unity desktop.

The command line isn't difficult for this, so maybe you would like to try this:
Suppose you want to make an encrypted folder inside your home folder called "locked". Open the command terminal and type:
encfs ~/.locked ~/locked (notice the space before each tilde mark)
This command creates both the visible and the hidden folder (hidden one has a dot at the start). encfs then asks for the password (which you want to type carefully) and the encryption level (just press enter for the default).
If you open your home folder in Nautilus or any file browser you'll see the visible 'locked' folder. When you put anything in the visible 'locked' folder it is really being encrypted and stored in the hidden '.locled' folder.
In reality the encrypted folder is mounted in the visible folder. To verify this type:
fusermount -u ~/locked (this unmounts the encrypted 'locked' folder)
and then in your file browser you'll see that everything you had put in that folder is now "missing". (It is really in the hidden .locked folder, all encrypted and safe.) To access this folder again just type: encfs ~/.locked ~/locked
then type your password. You'll see your files again in the visible 'locked' folder.

So what I've suggested is the command line stuff that cryptkeeper would have done under the surface. Hope it's useful!